# providing a default value for where statement in linq that uses querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

lets first see my codes

```
protected void dsVsl_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
{
    string query;
    if (Request.QueryString["[VARIABLE]"] != "" && Request.QueryString["[VARIABLE]"] != null)
    {
        query = "";
    }
    else
    {
        query = Request.QueryString["vslCat"];
    } 
    e.Result = (from b in context.tblVessels
                where b.vApproval == true
                where b.vCat == query
                select new
                {
                    b.vAdType,
                    b.vCat,
                    b.vID,
                    b.vAdTitle,
                    b.vAdDesc,
                    b.vBuilder,
                    b.vBuildYear,
                }).ToList();
}
```

when the first time page loads there is no query-string present so I want to show the results with out any filters but it shows nothingggggggg!!!. and I know that i can place my linq statements in `if` and `else` blocks to have two different linq to ADO statements but I don't wanna do that!

Comment: `but I don't wanna do that!` And may we know why?

Comment: Cuase there is an answer  that I am looking for not this work around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first query you are checking if `b.vCat == ""` which is supposedly wrong for all rows you want to gather. Instead put an extra check in your `where` statement like this:

```
e.Result = (from b in context.tblVessels
            where b.vApproval == true
            where (query == "" || b.vCat == query)
            select new
            {
                b.vAdType,
                b.vCat,
                b.vID,
                b.vAdTitle,
                b.vAdDesc,
                b.vBuilder,
                b.vBuildYear,
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: `where (query == "" || b.vCat == query)`  dose it mean that if the query is empty ignore where statement?

Comment: In short, yes. You can think like that.

Answer (score 2):

Check for a null query value, *or* a match.

```
e.Result = (from b in context.tblVessels
            where b.vApproval == true
            where (String.IsNullOrEmpty(query) || b.vCat == query)
            select new
            {
                b.vAdType,
                b.vCat,
                b.vID,
                b.vAdTitle,
                b.vAdDesc,
                b.vBuilder,
                b.vBuildYear,
            }).ToList();
```